# Can I sue my gas company if they disconnect my service without notice?

Tags: texas, consumer-protection

On the 13th my gas was disconnected without notice.

When I called my gas company they said I was past due.  I paid them the same day.

My service was reconnected on the 15th.

On the 15th I got a letter saying my connection will be disconnected if I didn't pay before the 20th.

That means they disconnected me one week earlier than they gave notice.

What remedies do I have for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rule 7.45(4)(c) of the Railroad Commission rules](http://texreg.sos.state.tx.us/public/readtac$ext.TacPage?sl=T&app=9&p_dir=F&p_rloc=113616&p_tloc=14793&p_ploc=1&pg=2&p_tac=&ti=16&pt=1&ch=7&rl=45) allows disconnection of gas service for non-payment, stipulating that

> ...Proper notice consists of a deposit in the United States mail,
>   postage prepaid, or hand delivery to the customer at least five
>   working days prior to the stated date of disconnection, with the words
>   "Termination Notice" or similar language prominently displayed on the
>   notice....

If indeed the stated disconnection date was the 20th, then that would seem to be a violation. [This page](http://www.rrc.state.tx.us/media/26752/customer-information-on-your-gas-bill.pdf) provides basic information on complaints. Only your attorney can advise you whether there is practical utility or legal grounds for a lawsuit, but the email address on that page might be simpler.